Hide or disable .net runtime for testing purposes
Can you please give some advice on the next question: recently we moved our .net application to self-contained deployment. Before it was framework-dependent. Now we are thinking about testing this change. I think it's necessary just to run regression on a machine without .net runtime installed. But the problem is that on AWS clusters we are currently using to run the tests an image already contains .net runtime and we cannot remove it cause it's needed for the other apps. And my question: is it possible to hide or disable .net runtime before the particular test starts to imitate that .net runtime is not installed? I tried to temporarily remove C:\Program Files\dotnet from PATH but it didn't worked: .net runtime is still visible and other apps that are framework-dependent still runs well despite the removed string.
Do you probably know how I can test this change? Maybe "disabling" is not an option and there is another approach. I have to be sure that my app depends only on the libraries next to .exe and that all necessary libraries are present.
P.S. Regression tests are written with Python(in case it makes sense)
